# Focus change disturbing the UI in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the issue i was facing at my work. It can roughly be translated as follows.
Here goes the code.

```
<button style="margin:20px 0;">Click this button first and press tab </button>
<div class="div2"> 
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <span>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST</span>
    <button >moved out </button>
</div>

.div1
{
    width:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ff0;
    margin-left:50px;
}
div button
{
    
    width:50px;
    margin-left:180px;
    
}
.div2
{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

Please use this for better clarification [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dmw4/4/) in chrome and IE.

The problem is- if we press the first button and press tab the focus will move to the second button. Along with that the second button is appearing from partly hidden state and pushing the contents of the container div, which is making the UI distorted.

Actually behavior should be button should still be in hidden state and should not push the div.  Is there a simple way to handle this other than writing JS to push back the div again.

Comment: How should be the view before clicking on button and after clicking on it.

Comment: Both should be same. No change.

Comment: So you just want to show the hidden part of button.

Comment: As far as I remember, what you're describing here is/was the intended behavior as written in the CSS 2.1 specs. Not sure if that changed since. I personally think it makes total sense for it to be as it is, (partially) hiding a focusable / clickable element is just... bad.

Comment: @gpgekko: Can you just point me to the specs which states that if you have it open. I'm kind of lost searching for it. So that i can back my argument.

Comment: @wh0 Sorry, this is all served up from memory. I'll try to dig it up, but I don't remember any details about where exactly it is defined.